# getting files with max dates

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list of files:

fileA_20180103110932
fileA_20180103111001
fileB_20180103110901
fileC_20180103110932
fileC_20180103111502

Per file name, I need to get the latest date.  So the result set would be:

fileA_20180103111001
fileB_20180103110901
fileC_20180103111502

How would I do that with lambda expressions?

on a high level, I think I have to group by file names (so do a substring till the underscore) and then get the max date for those file names that have a count > 2.

Comment: I'm sure you tried something! Please show your efforts so we can see where *specifically* you need help. Currently it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Can you do it without lambdas? Why do you want lambdas? Just because C# supports lambdas, we don't need to use it everywhere

Comment: @Thomas Weller - I can do it without lambdas.  I can loop thru the file names and compare the old file name with the new file name and if they equal each other, get the latest date.

Comment: Are you sure that comparing the date in the name is the best idea? What if 2 files are named exactly the same?... then you'll need to check the actual date to compare them, why not doing this directly?

Comment: File names will never have the same name as they'll always have a different time stamp.

Comment: @rds80 your timestamp "precision" is in seconds, I don't know your context, but it's not strange that 2 (or more) files are created within the same second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var files = new List<string>
{
    "fileA_20180103110932",
    "fileA_20180103111001",
    "fileB_20180103110901",
    "fileC_20180103110932",
    "fileC_20180103111502"
};

var results = files
    .Select(f => f.Split('_'))
    .GroupBy(p => p[0], p => p[1])
    .Select(g => g.Key + "_" + g.Max());
```

Comment: That worked! How do I not include a file name that doesn't include "Consolidated" in the name.  I tried .Where(x => !x.Contains("Consolidated")) after the first select, but that didn't work.

Comment: Had to include the where clause after the second select statement.

Comment: I would prefer to insert a where clause at the very first, as that is more efficient. For example, if you want to exclude all files with string "A", you can write: files.Where(f => !f.Contains("A")).Select(f => f.Split('_'))....

Answer (score 0):

Apparently all your files have exactly one underscore in their file names. The fact that you define the part after the underscore as the "date of the file" is irrelevant to your problem. What is relevant is that your filenames have an underscore, a part before the underscore and a part after the underscore.

Besides, a filename is not a file, it is just a string with some limitations, especially your coded filenames

So your problem would be like this:

Given a sequence of strings, where every string has exactly one underscore. The part before the underscore is called MainPart, the part after the underscore is called SortablePart (this is what you would call the "date of the file").

Your requirement would be:

> I want a linq statement that has as input this sequence of strings and
>   as output a sequence of strings containing the MainPart of the input
>   strings, followed by an underscore, followed by the first value of all
>   SortableParts of strings with the same MainPart ordered in descending
>   order.

Having rephrased your problem your linq statement is fairly easy. You'll need a function to split your input strings into MainPart and SortablePart. I'll do this using [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var result = fileNames
    .Select(inputString => inputString.Split(new char[] {'_'}))
    .Select(splitStringArray => new
    {
        MainPart = splitStringArray[0],
        SortablePart = splitStringArray[1],
    })
    // now easy to group by MainPart:
    .GroupBy(
        item => item.MainPart,        // make groups with same MainPart, will be the key
        item => item.SortablePart)    // the elements of the group
     // for every group, sort the elements descending and take only the first element
     .Select(group => new
     {
         MainPart = group.Key,
         NewestElement = group                               // take all group elements
            .SortByDescending(groupElement => groupElement)  // sort in descending order
            .First(),
      })
      // I know every group has at least one element, otherwise it wouldn't be a group
      // now form the file name:
      .Select(item => item.MainPart + '_' + item.NewestElement);
```

> **This is one horrible linq statement!**

Besides it will crash if your file names have no underscore at all. It is very difficult to guarantee the filenames are all correctly coded.

If your coded filenames are something you widely use in your application, my advise would be to create a class for this and some functions to make conversion to filename (string) and back easier. This would make your coded filenames easier to understand by others, easier to change if needed, and above all: you can be certain that the filenames are coded correctly

```
class CodedFileName
{
    private const char separator = '_';
    public string MainPart {get; private set;}
    public string TimePart {get; private set;}
}
```

This makes it easier if you decide to change your separator, or accept several separators (old filenames using underscore, and new filenames using minus sign)

You'd also need a propert constructor:

```
public CodedFileName(string mainPart, DateTime fileDate) {...}
```

And maybe constructors that takes a filename. Exceptions if not coded:

```
public CodedFileName(string fileName) {..}
public CodedFileName(FileInfo fileInfo) {...}

public bool IsProperlyCoded(string fileName) {...}
```

and of course a ToString():

```
public override ToString()
{
    return this.MainPart + separator + this.TimePart;
}
```

TODO: if needed consider defining equality, IEquatable, IComparable, ICloneable, etc.

Having done this, the advantages are that you are certain that your filenames will always be properly coded. Much easier to understand by others, much easier to change, and thus maintain, and finally your linq query will be much easier (to understand, maintain, test, etc):

As an extension function: [see Extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
static class CodedFileNameExtensions
{
    public static CodedFileName Newest(this IEnumerable<CodedFileName> source)
    {
        // TODO: exception if null or source empty
        return source.OrderByDescending(sourceElement => sourceElement.TimePart)
             .First();
    }

    public static CodedFileName NewestOrDefault(this IEnumerable<CodedFileName> source)
    {
         // TODO: exception if null source
         if (source.Any())
            return source.Newest();
         else
            return null;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<CodedFileName> ExtractNewest(this IEnumerable<CodedFileName> source)
    {
        return groupsSameNamePart = source
            .GroupBy(sourceElement => sourceElement.MainPart)
            .Newest(group => group)
    }
}
```

Usage will be:

```
IEnumerable<string> fileNames = ...
IEnumerable<string> correctlyCodedFileNames = fileNames
    .Where(fileName => fileName.IsCorrectlyCoded();

IEnumerable<CodedFileName> codedFileNames = correctlyCodedFileNames
   .Select(correctlyCodedFileName => new CodedFileName(correctlyCodedFileName));
IEnumerable<CodedFileName> newestFiles = codedFileNames.ExtractNewest();
```

Or in one statement:

```
IEnumerable<CodedFileName> newestFiles = fileNames
    .Where(fileName => fileName.IsCorrectlyCoded)
    .Select(fileName => new CodedFileName(fileName)
    .ExtractNewest();
```

Now isn't that much easier to understand? And all this by less then one page of coding.

So if you use your coded file names all over your project, my advise would be to consider creating a class for it.